# Cannot pass in props as JSON when using ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs

New to react. I found that when trying to pass a JSON into a component, it won't work:

```
    const stepData = {firstname: "yo", lastname: "kk"}
    console.log(stepData)
    ReactDOM.render(
        <StepResult data={stepData} />, document.getElementById("execution-result-panel"))
```

Inside `StepResult`, if I do `this.props.data.firstname`, it will show `undefined`.

But if the data is a String, it will work:

```
    const stepData = "some data"
    console.log(stepData)
    ReactDOM.render(
        <StepResult data={stepData} />, document.getElementById("execution-result-panel"))
```

So react does not support such passing? Do I need to do `<StepResult firstname={stepData.firstname} />`?

Comment: where is the code for `<StepResult>`? what is your definition of "work"?

Comment: If StepResult is a functional component then use props.data.firstname

Answer (score 3):

React does support complex objects in properties, you can see all the properties with a log statement such as:

`console.log(this.props)`

Or even better use the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension.